# filter doesn't trigger events for my contract

Tags: web3js, events, metamask, filters

I have a trivial contract and I want to get notification of all events for the contract. But I don't see any events being called for my contract:

```
contract MainContract{
    event Evt(address indexed _sender,string jsn);
    function deposit(string jsn) returns (int256) {
        Evt(msg.sender, jsn);
    }
}

var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at("0xe45866ac5d51067ce292bc656c790e94ddcf0766");
        web3.eth.filter({},function(err,res) {
            console.log("on filter",res.address);
        });
        contract.deposit('hello there',function (res) {
            console.log(arguments)
        });
```

You can see in console that deposit() worked successfully, but no callback calls matching my address call present in console. Why is this? Is this expected behaviour?

[image: console screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using my wallet address instead of contract address here:

> web3.eth.contract(abi).at("0xe45866ac5d51067ce292bc656c790e94ddcf0766")

current web3 API doesn't inform if address here is incorrect...